# How can I zero out only the USED space on a storage drive?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, formatting

I have a large drive (4TB) that I've only written a few gigabytes to. I'm giving it to a friend, so I'd like to zero it out. I know I can zero out the whole drive with `dd`, but I'd like to know if:

1. zeroing only the non-zero bits will be faster, and
2. if so, how to go about doing that.

EDIT: I trust my friend and there's nothing sensitive on the drive anyway, so no worries if zeroing isn't a bullet-proof method of erasing.

Comment: Simple answer, overwrite it with anything meaningless, then delete it all.

Comment: The sectors that are non-zero could be in-use sectors or deleted sectors, and could be anywhere on the drive. There is no efficient method of finding every non-zero sector other than a search by actual reading. Simply overwriting without bothering to read would actually be faster. Anything less than overwriting *every* sector would be a half-baked job that could leave some sectors untouched. Since you "*trust your friend*", you could simply delete all the partitions, or reformat all partitions. Then there are no directories or files to look at unless an intentional recovery is attempted.

Comment: Note that it's not only about trusting your friend.  It could also involve trusting whomever they give/sell the drive to on a future date, *ad infinitum*.  That said, you mention that there's nothing sensitive on the drive, so as sawdust mentioned, simply deleting or reformatting the partitions may be sufficient.

Comment: @sawdust I agree with most of what you wrote, except that if most of drive is empty, and we are dealing with an HDD, reading the whole thing and only writing over non-zero sectors is likely much faster than writing over the entire drive.  This is because writing is a much slower operation than reading.  And if we are dealing with an SSD, then filling the entire drive with random bytes is really the only choice.  Of course, since the data isn't sensitive, your suggestion of simply deleting/reformatting partitions will likely be sufficient, and has the added benefit of being fast.

Comment: @sawdust BTW, this answer (https://superuser.com/a/1511397/380110) is contrary to my experience and the many controlled tests that I have run, but I'm always open to the possibility that my experience isn't everyone's experience and that significant hardware differences can yield significantly different results.

Comment: @EndAnti-SemiticHate - The OP claims that he's "*only written a few gigabytes*".  Not clear if that's the current amount of "*used space*" mentioned in the title, or the grand total for the life of the drive. I'm inclined to assume the former rather than the later. So you really don't know how many, nor where there are non-zero sectors that need to be zeroed.  "*This is because writing is a much slower operation than reading.*" -- Not true, and agree with that accepted answer. FWIW I have firmware experience dealing with file operations in the kernel down to the magnetic flux on the platter.

Comment: @EndAnti-SemiticHate The overriding factor in large sequential hdd disk operations is the time spent positioning the heads.  This is true and similar for both reading and writing for bith CMR and SMR drives.

Comment: @sawdust it occurred to me just now that SMR drives have slow sustained writes. Can you confirm my (googled) understanding that this is relevant to random writes but not sequential ones? If Im wrong, could it indeed be possible that for SMR drives it could actually be faster to read the entire drive if the amounts to write are small enough and we could find/write a program to do this?

Comment: @davidgo "and we could find/write a program to do this" – Already done: https://superuser.com/a/1722580/432690

Comment: @davidgo - My experience is limited to conventional hard drives. I won't speculate on SMR performance.

Comment: @davidgo "*The overriding factor in large sequential hdd disk operations is the time spent positioning the heads.*" - Not always true, rotational delay can be a significant contributor. A slow program or interface could force a 2 revolutions-per-read-write-sector  sequence into requiring an additional rotation to total 3 revolutions.

Answer (score 2):

Zeroing out non-zero bytes is likely to be error prone and not significantly faster - indeed it's likely to be slower and you will need to read the whole disk to determine what needs to be read.

If you are not overly concerned, and the disk is fairly new (i.e. does not have a lot of fragmentation), you may want to try only overwriting the first X gigabytes of the drive.  You can do this with `dd` and limiting the number of blocks written - but I might be inclined to use `pv` and just write until I am tired of it (`pv` shows how much has been piped through it - so is a reasonable proxy of how much has been cleared).  I might use a command like:

```
pv < /dev/zero > /dev/sdX
```

You can use crtl + c to stop.

Comment: (1) `pv < /dev/null` exits immediately. Do you mean `/dev/zero`? (2) Please review "you will need to read the whole disk to determine what needs to be read".